# Parse a String and Append Incremented Number using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing

I have the following code that parses this string and converts it into an Object. Because there are duplicate keys in it, I need to append an incremented number to each key.

```
    var str = 'View\n{\n    Name: View1;\n    Image\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Image.gif;\n        Position: 0, 0;\n        Width: 320;\n        Height: 480;\n    }\n\n    Button\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Button.gif;\n        Transition: View2;\n        Position: 49, 80;\n        Width: 216;\n        Height: 71;\n    }\n\n    Button\n    {\n        BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;\n        Position: 65, 217;\n        Width: 188;\n        Height: 134;\n    }\n\n    Label\n    {\n        Position: 106, 91;\n        Width: 96;\n        Height: 34;\n        Text: "Button";\n        FontSize: 32;\n        Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;\n    }\n    Scroll\n    {\n        Position: 106, 91;\n        Width: 96;\n        Height: 34;\n        Button{\n            BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;\n            Position: 65, 217;\n            Width: 188;\n            Height: 134;\n        }\n        Button{\n            BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;\n            Position: 65, 217;\n            Width: 188;\n     \n      Height: 134;\n        }\n\n    }\n\n}';

str = str.replace(/(\w+)\s*\{/g, "$1:{"); // add in colon after each named object
str = str.replace(/\}(\s*\w)/g, "},$1"); // add comma before each new named object
str = str.replace(/;/g, ","); // swap out semicolons with commas
str = str.replace(/,(\s+\})/g, "$1"); // get rid of trailing commas
str = str.replace(/([\d\.]+(, [\d\.]+)+)/g, "[$1]"); // create number arrays
str = str.replace(/"/g, ""); // get rid of all double quotes
str = str.replace(/:\s+([^\[\d\{][^,]+)/g, ':"$1"');  // create strings

$("pre").html(str);
```

In this working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T59fL/2/
I need to append an incremented number onto anything that has ':{' at the end of it. i.e. View, Button, Button, Image, etc would turn into View1, Button1, Button2, Image1, etc1

Comment: solved http://jsfiddle.net/GaX6E/2/

Comment: Post it as answer if you have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved jsfiddle.net/GaX6E/2

```
var i = 0;
str = str.replace(/([^:]+):{/g, function(m, p1) { return p1 + "_" + (++i).toString() + ":{"; });
```